# DjangoのImageFieldから画像を圧縮してGoogle Cloud Storageに保存したい

Tags: django, google-cloud-storage

DjangoのImageFieldを使ってGoogle Cloud Storageに画像をアップロードする際に、画像を圧縮したいです。
pythonではgzipを使えばファイルの圧縮はできますが、どこに処理を書けばいいのでしょうか？
また、djangoで圧縮後のファイルサイズの制限やアップロードするファイルサイズの上限はどのように設定できますか？

環境情報：
Django2.1.5, python3.7.0, django-storages1.7.1

Comment: もう少し何をどうしたいか詳細を追記した方が良いと思います。検索して見つかるのは、サムネイルに変換したり、画像の品質を下げて、サイズ削減する方法ですが、それが希望するものとも思えないので。

Comment: ソースコードの抜粋（画像をアップロードする処理）を質問に追加して下さい。